# Docker Run command hangs without any error

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have been working with docker in Windows Server 2016 only for the last two weeks. I am trying to run a html file using

```
microsoft/windowsservercore (docker image)
```

After I execute the command

```
docker run -it --name CoreServerCMD microsoft/windowsservercore cmd.exe
```

the execution hangs and do not return.

please help this is image reference:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5H37.png)

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but did you run the diagnose tool? Sometimes it gives hints about missing updates and such.

Comment: I did not check with any diagnose tools yet. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Also when I check **Task Manager - > Performance** noticed that there are some network activity going on after executing the command.

Comment: You should find an entry for "Diagnose and Feedback" in the Docker for Windows app icon/context menu.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016. Things are working fine when I switch to linux container and try running nginx image. But windows container and try to run iis image it is not working

Comment: Ah, sorry, then you can follow the descriptions there: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/windows-server-container-tools/Debug-ContainerHost/README.md - in essence: run `Invoke-WebRequest https://aka.ms/Debug-ContainerHost.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression` in a PowerShell

Comment: After running the command in PowerShell am getting only one error status as follows:

 [-] Has KB3192366, KB3194496, or later installed if running Windows build 14393 443ms
   Expected {0} to be greater than or equal to {351}
   13:             (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name UBR).UBR | Should
Not BeLessThan 351
   at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Docker\Debug-ContainerHost.ps1: line 13

Comment: So i guess you should now check for your Windows build number (expected 14393) and whether you could apply the mentioned Updates (KB3192..., KB3194...).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This is not an error: the docker image is being downloaded from the docker hub. According to https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/tags/ the image is 5GB large, so this is a long time to download.
I suggest that you wait at least an hour, depending on your broadband.

**Update after feedback:** it seems this is not precisely the issue the author encountered - the provided answer works for other OS than Windows. See comments for more details.

Comment: Looking at the provided Screenshot (at the _Error_ link), the image is already downloaded.

Comment: Yes the image is already downloaded and it is listing in my local repository. I can see it with the command "docker images".

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The docker image is already downloaded, having the same problem with nginx (which is not large at all).

Comment: Same issue here, I made sure to pull the image first before issuing the `docker run` command, it's stuck trying to run it as well.

Answer (score 19):

You are running the 'docker run' command with '-it' flag. You need to include '-d' flag instead of '-it'.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to [Avik Aggarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095619/docker-run-command-hangs-without-any-error/55018417#55018417) answer, even with `-d` flag didn't work for me. Increasing Docker's RAM (resources) in Settings solved the problem.

Comment: I increased swap file and ram and works now